# I'm having issues trying to parseFloat something and it returns NaN

Tags: javascript, numbers, parsefloat

Well I have this

[image]

and I'm doing this

```js
function CheckLevel() {
  var PlyLevel = parseFloat(document.getElementById("player_level").innerHTML);
  return PlyLevel
}
alert(CheckLevel());
```

```html
<div id="player_level">level 338</div>
```

And get back

```
NaN
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: what is the **exact** contents of `player_level`

Comment: What is the value of "document.getElementById("player_level").innerHTML" ?

Comment: `I have this` - that's an IMAGE ... you'll need to write an OCR program in javascript to get a number out of that

Comment: I got what i needed working, and that was just showing what's shown not what i was using to get the number.

Answer (score 1):

In your case string not starts with digit so it will always returns `NaN`.

> If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat returns NaN. (Taken from [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseFloat)).

So get float value using regex and parse it.`match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)` will match any float value from the string.

```js
function CheckLevel() {
  var PlyLevel = parseFloat(document.getElementById("player_level").innerHTML.match(/\d+(?:\.\d+)?/)[0]);
  return PlyLevel
}
alert(CheckLevel());
```

```html
<div id="player_level">level 332.3</div>
```

**[Regex explanation here](https://regex101.com/r/gU0mG2/1)**

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Comment: It worked! now, what does anything you put in there actually mean.

Comment: @JamesB : If the first character cannot be converted to a number, parseFloat returns NaN